# Как удерживать отправку данных на сервер через js?

Tags: javascript, django, form

Есть форма.

```
<form name="regex101">
    <input type="text" id="name"  placeholder="Атыңыз" onkeypress="onpress_name()">
    <span id="console_name"></span>

    <input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Телефон нөмірі">
    <span id="console_tel"></span>

    <input type="submit" value="ОК" id="btn">

</form>
```

Comment: Я по заголовку так и не понял, что вам нужно

Comment: Удерживать это как? если хотите при отправке на сервер заморозить на время используйте setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);

Comment: смотрите когда я нажимаю Submit то он отправляет. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии джаваскрипт чекалформу и если есть ошибка то выдавал и делал focus() последовательно. Не могу придумать через цикл форик помогите плиз

Answer (score 0):

Уберите тип `submit` у поля со значением "OK". Сделайте его не input, а например:

`<button id="btn">OK</button>`

И там же отправьте потом через XHR после всех обработок.

Comment: К вашему сведению, button'ы тоже отправляют формы, попробуйте

Comment: можно по подробнее. Ваш ответ субьективен